# How to see debug logs for WireGuard (e.g. to see authentication attempts)

Tags: debian-buster, wireguard

I've successfully set up a [WireGuard VPN](https://www.wireguard.com/) on my Debian 10 server. It was incredibly straight forward compared to the setup of OpenVPN, and it's working fine.

However, I can't see any logs beyond those from `journalctl -u wg-quick@wg0.service`. I'd like to know, for example, when there are failed authentication attempts. Is there a way to monitor that? e.g. with openvpn I could use fail2ban based on auth attempts.

Answer (score 36):

Assuming you are running a kernel which supports dynamic debugging, you can enable debug logs by executing:

```
# modprobe wireguard 
# echo module wireguard +p > /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control
```

The logs can than be consumed via `dmesg` or `journalctl`. With `dmesg`, just use following command:

```
$ dmesg -wH
```

(`-H`, `--human` enables user-friendly features like colors, relative time)

(`-w`, `--follow`)

Also on systems with systemd you can use:

```
$ journalctl -kf
```

Comment: Alas I'm on Debian buster 4.19 kernel. Thanks though.

Comment: @artfulrobot The newer kernel version could be installed easily via the buster-backports channel if you don't mind a reboot.

Comment: How do you reverse `+p` thing once I'm done? I'm trying to debug a WireGuard client issue, how do I point `journalctl` to consume the appropriate log?

Comment: For CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG kernels, any settings given at boot-time (or enabled by -DDEBUG flag during compilation) can be disabled later via the sysfs interface if the debug messages are no longer needed: `echo "module module_name -p" > <debugfs>/dynamic_debug/control`. You can read the docs [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.11/admin-guide/dynamic-debug-howto.html)

Comment: worth mentioning that in minimal setups or containers you may need to enable the `debugfs` via `sudo mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug/`

Comment: You say 5.6 kernel is required but that works fine with AlmaLinux 8.3 (kernel 4.18.0)

Comment: @Winand Sorry, don't know why I thought that a 5.6 kernel would be necessary, I removed that section. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

To automatically activate *wireguard*'s dynamic debug logging directly at boot, have the `wireguard` kernel module

- load at boot time
- with the dynamic debug option

```
# automatically modprobe wireguard during boot:
echo "wireguard" | sudo tee /etc/modules-load.d/wireguard.conf

# automatically activate dynamic_debug for wireguard during boot:
echo "options wireguard dyndbg=+p" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/wireguard.conf
```

(Reference: [*Debug Messages at Module Initialization Time* from kernel.org documentation](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/dynamic-debug-howto.html#debug-messages-at-module-initialization-time))

The *wireguard*-specific log entries can then be followed/monitored with any of the following commands:

```
sudo journalctl -x -f -g wireguard*

sudo dmesg -wH --color=always | grep -i wireguard
```

Answer (score 2):

My version of logging users, script in crontab every 3 minutes. If inactivity less then 180 seconds, nothing doing, else appending to a log file.

```
wg show all dump | grep 10.0 | awk 'BEGIN {}; {if (systime()-$6 <180 ) print strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S", systime()),$5, $4, (systime()-$6) "sec" } ; END {}' >> /var/log/wg.log
```

Note: Searching for `10.0` in the output, because that is what IP addresses in my private network start with.